# How to best combine data from key-value stores and databases

Tags: database, nosql, key-value

Let's assume we have a friend list table for a social network.

Most use cases will require the friend list table to be JOINed to another table where you hold the personal details, such as: Name, Age, City, Profile picture URL, Last login time, etc...

Once the friend list table is in the 100M rows range. Querying a JOIN like this can take a few seconds. If you introduce a few other WHERE conditions it can even be slower.

A key-value store systems can bring in the friend list very quickly.

Let's assume we would like to show the 10 most recently logged in friends of a user.
What is the best way to calculate this output? A few methods I've been thinking about are below. Do any of them make sense?

- Shall we keep all data in the key-value store environment? Update the
  key-value store with every new login?
- Or shall we pull the friend list id's first. Then use a database command like "IN()" and query the database?
- Merge the data at the client level? A javascript solution?

Comment: i would have the friend list part in a fast storage, and use an 'IN' query rather than a join

Answer (score 0):

In your Users table you have a field to save a timestamp for last login. In your table were the friend-relationships are stored you have 1 row per relationship and that makes the table really long.

So joining these tables seems bad and we should optimize this process somehow? The answer is: No, not necessarily. The people who construct a DBMS have the same problems as you and they implement the tools to solve them. Every DBMS has some sort of query optimization which is smarter than you and me.

So there's no shame in joining long tables. If you want to try to optimize you may:

- Get the IDs of the friends of the user.
- Get the information you want of the first 10 friends sorted by last_login desc where the id fits (and other where conditions).

You don't need to join the tables, but you will use two queries, so maybe if your DBMS is smart a join is faster (Maybe run a test).

If you want to, you can use ajax to load this data after the page was loaded, this improve the experience for the user, but the traffic on the DB will be the same.

I hope this helped.

Edit: Oh yeah, if you already knew the friends IDs (you need them for other stuff) you wouldn't even need a join. You can pass the IDs over to the javascript which loads the last login list  later via AJAX.